# iTunes: Can I show all of my podcasts in one view, so that I can sort by date?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I have a few podcasts that I just subscribed to that I would like to listen through in order by date.

Is there a way to show all podcasts in one list view?  If not, is there a way to sort my podcasts by the oldest unwatched episode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a Smart Playlist.

1. Click File -> New Smart Playlist
2. Configure the rule so it reads "Media Kind is Podcast"
3. Make sure the "Limit to" box is unchecked, and that the "Live updating" box is
4. Click OK

[image]

Once this is done you will have a playlist with all your podcasts. To sort by date, right click the column bar at the top and check "Release Date". Click on the Release Date column to sort your podcasts by date.

The only downside to this view is that this view does not provide the blue dot that indicates whether or not a podcast has been listened to. You can, however, add the "Plays" column and use that instead, as podcasts that have not been listened to will have a play count of "0". You can also have the smart playlist automatically remove played podcasts from the list by editing it and adding the rule "Plays is 0".

Comment: Add colums "Plays" or "Last Played" to see what has been listened to.

Comment: @mankoff: True. That won't show the blue dot, but it will provide some visual indicator

Comment: Awesome.  Is there any way to get the dot to show?

Comment: @John As far as I can tell, no

Answer (score 2):

- Make a Smart Folder with "Media Kind is Podcast".
- Add a column (CTRL+click on column headers) for "Release Date".
- Sort.